# Why use dot *and* bracket access to assign a property?

Tags: javascript, properties

I've just found the following line in Knockout's source code:

```
target.subscribe = target['subscribe'] = function …
```

Why are they assigning the function to the same property twice? The only difference is the way they access it. As far as I know this shouldn't make a difference with the given property name ([JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4968406/1048572)).

Comment: @Bergi I reopened this because it's not a duplicate of the general question of which should be used. This question is about why some code is using BOTH, seemingly redundantly.

Comment: @Barmar: Yeah, I saw. I wanted to edit the title and then reopen it myself :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that this is done to prevent things breaking when code is minified.

`target.subscribe` can be minified to something like `target.a`, however there may be code that relies on `target.subscribe` still being there. For instance, you might have:

```
var x = 'subscribe';
target[x](something);
```

Assigning to both will allow the minifier to do its work, without breaking support for expression access.

Comment: That explains why they need to do `target['subscribe']`, but why do they ALSO need to do `target.subscribe`?

Comment: @Barmar That's the one that will be minified, thus saving space.

Comment: Wouldn't it save more space if there were no second assignment at all?

Comment: Certainly. But if you have `target.subscribe` many times in your code, then they can all be minified. `target.subscribe` is the preferred format when minifying. `target['subscribe']` is simply there to provide compatibility for expression-based access.

Comment: That makes sense! I checked the minified version and it reads `b.V=b.subscribe=function...`. But that also means you end up with two different properties and you always need to be aware which one you are reading or writing. Sounds like a good source for bugs.

Comment: @user232986 Maybe if you're working with strings or numbers, but for a function (or any other object) there is only ever one object with two references pointing to it - no bugs there.